# How to exchange data between a form, a php file and a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

Hi I am new to web development and I need help on this.

I have a php page called index.php where I take a date range from the user. The date range entered by the user is this passed on to process.php where data relevant in the date range is pulled from the database. Now this data is to be sent to a javascript file which will create a chart(using Highcharts) in index.php using the data.

The codes for the different files are:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Scripts for calender -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" src="assets/js/calender.js"></script>

    <!-- Scripts which render the charts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>

    <!-- php files for data retrieval and formatting for charts -->
    <?php  include "process.php"?>
</head>
<body>
<!-- form to input daterange -->
<form name="daterange" id="daterange" action="index.php" method="post">
            <table id="table">
                <th>Select Date range</th>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="from">From</label>
                        <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <label for="to">To</label>
                            <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </form>
    <?php if (isset($_POST["from"]) && isset($_POST["to"])) { getdata($_POST["from"], $_POST["to"]); } ?>

<!-- div to render the chart -->
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="dash-unit" id="chartdiv">
            <dtitle>Top 10 Hash Sources</dtitle>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

process.php

```
<?php
        function getdata($from, $to)
        {
        include 'sqlserverConn.php';


        $query="select name, stats from table where date >= '".$from."' and date <= '".$to."'";

        $query_result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

        $r1 = array();

        $result = array();
        $r1['type']='pie';
        $r1['name']='data chart';
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query_result))
        {
            $r1['data'][]=array($row['name'],$row['stats']);

        }

        array_push($result, $r1);

        print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

        }

?>
```

chart.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                        var options = {
                            chart: {
                                renderTo: 'chartdiv',

                                marginRight: 70,
                                marginBottom: 25
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'data chart',
                                x: -20, //center
                            },
                            subtitle: {
                                text: '',
                                x: -20
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    allowPointSelect: true,
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    showInLegend: true
                                }
                            },

                            legend: {
                                enabled: true,
                                layout: 'vertical',
                                align: 'right',
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                x: -10,
                                y: 100,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            },
                            series: []

                        }

                        $.getJSON("process.php", function(json) {

                            options.series[0] = json[0];

                            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                        });
                    });
```

Now when I enter the date range, the data is echoed on index.php rather than the chart.

This process works fine when I don't have to take any input from the user and just display a chart made from a query.

Please tell me where I am wrong and how can I achieve what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting exactly what you've entered: after the form is submitted and all fields are filled, it just prints the json encoded results.

What you're looking for is creating a asynchronous call to process.php *including* the form values. In your chart.js:

```
$(document).ready({

    ...

    $('#daterange').submit( function(){
        var from = encodeURIComponent( $('#from').val() );
        var to = encodeURIComponent( $('#to').val() );
        $.getJSON("process.php?from=" + from + "&to=" + to, function(json) {
            options.series[0] = json[0];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
});
```

And in your process.php:

```
if( isset( $_GET['from'] ) && isset( $_GET['to' ) ){
    getData( $_GET['from'], $_GET['to'];
}
```

Comment: The data is still not going to the javascript file but is being echoed on index.php

Comment: For me its the best way and should work, data is empty which you receive?

Comment: @SebastianBochan No the data received is not empty.